# Mysqli query return empty results

Tags: php, mysqli

im trying to get some data from my DB using this code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);


$mysqli2 = new mysqli(********************);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
   }

    $sql2 = "SELECT message FROM wall_workouts_names WHERE id = ? ";

    $stmt2 = $mysqli2->prepare($sql2) or trigger_error($mysqli2->error."[$sql2]");

    $id_for_wall = '43';

    $stmt2->bind_param('s', $id_for_wall);

    $stmt2->execute();

    $stmt2->bind_result($message);

    $stmt2->store_result();

    $stmt2->fetch();

        echo $message;

?>
```

My problem is that i get empty string in my echo.

But if i run the same query in my phpmyadmin i get good results.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Although this question is a sure too localized one, +1 for having error reporting almost proper.

Comment: To make it straight: your code *looks* all right. As much as a human can tell. To investigate a problem you have to run your code and debug it. The sooner you understand it the sooner you have your code working.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there are no row to match condition in your WHERE clause, namely with id = 43

Comment: Try to run it right here with a hardcoded (not bound) value and see. Using query()/fetch_array()

Comment: I tried hardcoded and i get empty result.
But when i use it in my phpadmin, same query, i get good result...

Comment: **WEll, you are querying another database with your phpmyadmin then**

Comment: Its not, im sure about it.

Comment: You'd better trust your eyes, not speculations. This is a most important skill a developer have to develop. Try to select all the records from the table and see.

Comment: i tried using this code: 'if($stmt2->num_rows > 0)
       echo $message;    
   else
  echo 'empty';'
and i dont get "empty" in my echo. its means that i do get result from my DB but i get empty string and not the string that i have in my db

Comment: if you have num_rows > 0 (what is exact value by the way?) you should have your row using query()/fetch_array(), but you said you haven't. Anyway, I am here not to urge you to debug your code. If you won't - nobody can do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Check your incoming results like this.

```
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   echo $message;    
 }
```

Comment: this code is useless itself and won't help to solve the particular problem in question.