# Mysqli query returns empty string

Tags: php, mysqli

In progress of this issue:

[Mysqli query return empty results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699123/mysqli-query-return-empty-results)

This is my php code:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$mysqli2 = new mysqli('');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
   }

    $sql2 = "SELECT message FROM wall_workouts_names WHERE id = '43' ";

    $stmt2 = $mysqli2->prepare($sql2) or trigger_error($mysqli2->error."[$sql2]");

    $stmt2->execute();

    $stmt2->bind_result($message);

    $stmt2->store_result();

     $stmt2->fetch();

    if($stmt2->num_rows > 0)
       echo $message;    
   else
        echo 'empty';    

?>
```

From this code i get empty string as a result.

This is my table in phpmyadmin

[image]

When i run the same code but with this query:

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT workout_name FROM wall_workouts_names WHERE id = '43' ";
```

My echo is "t", as is should be.

But when i run this query:

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT message FROM wall_workouts_names WHERE id = '43' ";
```

I get empty string, something like this: "".

I dont understand what im doing wrong.

Comment: What is the return value of `$stmt2->bind_result($message);` ? Is it === true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this commenter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php#99159), the

> "proper procedure order is: `prepare -> execute -> store_result ->
>   bind -> fetch`."

I notice that you are calling `store_result()` AFTER you call `bind_result()`. Does changing the order of those calls make any difference?

Comment: Have you tried other sanity checks, like selecting `message` and `workout_name` together, and selecting the message from a different record besides id `43`?

Comment: I tried selecting different record, and still got empty string. BUT i tried selecting more than one column and its working, thank you.